# LSF nodes die after exhausting all memory

Tags: linux, memory, cluster

I have a LSF cluster and experience the following problems.

After some time, random OS processes start to die (they become zombies or defunct), and the LSF nodes do not report any troubles back to the NSF master.  I believe this to be caused by the LSF tasks exhausting the memory (128GB) on the nodes.

The tasks are run as a non-root LSF user.

> **Question.** How can I make the LSF tasks die instead of OS processes?

Any other suggestions and ideas will be appreciated.

(I hereby acknowledge that memory is difficult.)

Comment: PS., our current procedure is to try to find these "defect" nodes and set them as `status:offline`, wait and hope that all tasks complete, and then reboot them.

Comment: Hi.  In regard to your question about making LSF tasks die instead of the LSF daemon processes, this should be handled already.  LSF daemons will set `/proc/self/oom_adj` (or `oom_score_adj`) when the daemon starts up.  The LSF docs discuss it [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSETD4_9.1.3/lsf_admin/daemon_concepts_lsf.dita?lang=en).  Also, the `lim` process on the execution hosts will report regular load updates. If too many load updates are missed, the host will be marked as unavailable.  If the nodes don't move to unavail status, then maybe something else is going on.

Comment: Oh. This oom feature was added in version 9.1.1.

Comment: @MichaelClosson I think this is a good answer, especially if you can link to the introduction of feature in 9.1.1.